# Spring Data JPA save list entity return list in same the order?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

Does the method in Spring-Data-JPA's `CrudRepository`

```
 <S extends T> Iterable<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities)
```

return list in the same order ?

Comment: what is the spring data jpa version?

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5.8.RELEASE, spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

Comment: sorry, I edited the post, to list

Comment: I think it should be `saveAll` rather than `save`, reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html

Comment: @ArunSudhakaran this is an old question related to Spring Boot 1.x

Comment: Yes @tsarenkotxt its old question to those who interacted one year back. I just started working lately in spring and was confused for some time that's why I mentioned it. I hope anyone new will be getting confused that's why.

Comment: agree with you @ArunSudhakaran, how about the answer ? and the next version's changes? we can't update it every time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In that version an actual List is the return type:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> List<S> save(Iterable<S> entities) {

    List<S> result = new ArrayList<S>();

    if (entities == null) {
        return result;
    }

    for (S entity : entities) {
        result.add(save(entity));
    }

    return result;
}
```

so if you pass a List to the method, you will get the result in the exact same order as the ArrayList is the implementation.